# How to configure Ipv6 subnets for kubeadm setup of Kubernetes on a vlan?

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, kubeadm

I'm not understanding how to setup global ipv6 addressing for the pod network in a new dual stack kubernetes cluster.

My isp gives me an ipv6 subnet of: `2001:1234:1234::/48` for example

I have 3 vlans with subnets of:

```
2001:1234:1234:1::/64
2001:1234:1234:2::/64
2001:1234:1234:3::/64
```

I have 3 servers for kubernetes on the `2001:1234:1234:1::/64` vlan. When running the following:

```
kubeadm init \
    --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.10 \
    --control-plane-endpoint=example.com \
    --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16,2001:1234:1234:1:1::/80 \
    --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/16,2001:1234:1234:1:2::/112
```

I get the error that the pod network needs to be a /64 network like the nodes subnet

```
the size of pod subnet with mask 80 is smaller than the size of node subnet with mask 64
```

Sure I could just assign a new /64 subnet like `2001:1234:1234:4::/64` (because I want the global ips) But how would these be routable from my UDM-SE? When not on the vlan subnet? I don't understand how this part works or how to configure it here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a private ipv6 subnet and expose the services you need with metallb ip range created from the vlan ips, there enough to go around for everyone :)